# How do you specify the sourceBranch for a Run of Pipelines via the REST API?

Tags: api, rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been trying to run a pipeline for a particular branch of the repository I'm using.

In the UI, there is a convenient option, but I don't understand what to try in the request.

[image]

No matter what I do I always run from master.

How do I change that? I tried filling out the repository parameters but to no avail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#repositoryresourceparameters

Here is an example request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://dev.azure.com/<redacted>/<redacted>/_apis/pipelines/<redacted>/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <redacted>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: VstsSession=<redacted>' \
--data-raw '{   
    "previewRun": true,
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "refName": "refs/heads/<redacted>"
        }
    },
    "runParameters":
    {
        "namespace" : "<redacted>",
        "image" : "<redacted>",
        "tag" : "<redacted>",
        "package" : "<redacted>",
        "version" : "8.4.4"
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot, it seems that you are using the YAML pipeline.

I have tested your example , and the root cause of this issue is that the request body(data-raw) has some issues.

You could try my sample

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://dev.azure.com/<redacted>/<redacted>/_apis/pipelines/<redacted>/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <redacted>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: VstsSession=<redacted>' \
--data-raw '{   
"stagesToSkip":[],
    "resources":
    {
        "repositories":
        {
            "self":{"refName":"refs/heads/{Branchname}"}
            }

    },
    "templateParameters":
    {
        "namespace":"{value}",
        "image":"{value}",
        "tag":"{value}",
        "package":"{value}",
        "version":"{value}"
    },
    "variables":{}
}'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Its unclear if the curly braces in the `templateParameters` are required per syntax - if not could you use `< >` like OP did?

Answer (score 1):

For Http Request (you can test it with Postman)

**1. Get pipeline api url like this**
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Fill in your organization, project and pipelineId.
(all of this can be found in the link when you open your pipeline definition in Azure DevOps)

**2. Add Basic Auth headers**

key: Authorization, value:"Basic [your azure Person Access Token from Azure Dev Ops with Access to Pipeline goes here]"

Should look like this
"Basic OndzNWdz43FKfjdi98hjKDJFH8kkg9854HJKHF9D8RFEHui4387lkNXE="

And set content type to application/json

like this

key: Content-Type, value: application/json

**3. Put this JSON Into Raw Body**

```html
{
   "templateParameters":{
      "inputName":"johnsmith"
   },
   "resources":{
      "repositories":{
         "self":{
            "refName":"refs/heads/feature/#JIRATask01_Blabla"
         }
      }
   },
   "variables":{
      
   }
}
```

Replace refName value with branch you want to run the pipeline for.

If you have multiple repo pipeline look into this topic (but i haven't tested that solution):
[Azure DevOps API to Trigger Multi Repo changing branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71975102/azure-devops-api-to-trigger-multi-repo-changing-branches)