# Azure DevOps API to Trigger Multi Repo changing branches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

The Azure Devops pipeline is already defined with multiple repos and working as expected from Azure DevOps Tool, this Tool allows to change the branch names while triggering the build.

I am working on automating the build using a equivalent APIs and I would like to change the branch names for both the repos while triggering a build.

I am able to achieve apart of this by passing the sourceBranch for 1st repo using json request as mentioned below. I am not sure how to update the branch name for second repo in multiple repo build pipeline setup.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0

{
    "sourceBranch": "<branch-name>",
    "definition": {
        "id": 6
    }
}
```

[image]

Any help on this really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible in the build api, but it's available in the [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

In the body you can specify `resources`:

```
"resources":{"repositories":{"devops":{"refName":"refs/heads/test-branch","version":""},"self":{"refName":"refs/heads/master"}}},"variables":{}}
```