# Run Pipeline Rest API execution with branch name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Run Pipeline Rest API - execute with branch name
In our project, we are triggering pipeline through Runs REST API, following the steps mentioned in this page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 .
Now, we created the pipelines in feature branch and tried to invoke using the above API, we are getting below exception.

```
{
"$id": "1",
"innerException": null,
"message": "An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. File /delete.yml not found in repository https://dev.azure.com/{}/{}/_git/{} branch refs/heads/master version 201d2723d992a6ce0575838046970367098296a.",
"typeName": "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.PipelineValidationException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi",
"typeKey": "PipelineValidationException",
"errorCode": 0,
"eventId": 3000
}
```

When we add the pipeline yml file in master branch, we are able to trigger it using the API. But if we should not use the master branch, and use a different branch, how we can pass the branch parameter in this API call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you specify the sourceBranch for a Run of Pipelines via the REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66445303/how-do-you-specify-the-sourcebranch-for-a-run-of-pipelines-via-the-rest-api)

Comment: Hi Kushal Billakanti, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I've found a question about, I think, precisely the same issue; I hope the answer (that you need to specify the 'self' repository on the POST body) is useful to you.

Comment: Hi Kushal, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your issue:

[image]

**Reason:**

Each pipeline is based on a specific YML file. If you call the rest api to run the pipeline based on one branch of the repo, you must make sure there is a same name YML file in the branch.

The situation on my side:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Let me know whether this can solve your issue.

Comment: Sure thing. Have marked it.